# are project folders really necessary?

Tags: python, pycharm

I started programming recently, I'm using Python as language and PyCharm as editor. Most of my programs are't complex, I'd been using only files and not projects, and now I'm learning how to create packages.

I noticed that creating a project implies generate a folder with more folders and files inside. If I need to work in a bunch of projects I kind of feel that working in this way generate a waste of resources (repeated folders and files). Is this believe correct?

My last questing is how to determine when to work with packages and when with projects?

Comment: You may want to explicitly tag PyCharm in your question, as its concept of "projects" is not something that Python itself cares at all about. I'd not worry about the extra files being created. They're just the IDE's way of keeping track of your code, so it knows what relates to what (things in the same project are related, other stuff is not).

Comment: I understand the number of folders created can be confusing at first, but you're better off keeping them organized by project. As for space, they may take up more space on your screen, and require a few more clicks to navigate - but project folders and other generated files take up virtually no space.